# Checking the status of AsyncTask from another Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using `AsyncTask` to convert image to `base64` value. The task is running in the background and the app move to next activity. How can i check the status of the AsyncTask to check if it finishes or not...

My asynctask code...

```
public class Asyncimg extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
{
    //for converting images to base64

    protected void onPreExecute (){
        //disbaling sync button on converting pic to base64

    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
        Cursor cursor = mydb.getDat1();
        //fetching the image location
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            for( int i=0 ;  i< 1 ; i++ )
            {
                if( cursor.getColumnName(i) != null )
                {
                    try
                    {

                        if( cursor.getString(i) != null )
                        {
                            //saving image to bitmap
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PHOTO)));
                            //converting it to base64
                            String en= encodeToBase64( resize(bitmap,1080,1920), Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50);

                            Log.d("base",en);
                            //inserting it to table pic
                            mydb.insertpic(cursor.getInt(1),en);
                        }

                    }
                    catch( Exception ignored)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        mydb.updatebin();
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
```

How can i check its status from another activity.?

Comment: You need to share the AsyncTask via exposing an API/manager that can be queried to get the information you require. You could pass in a reference object from activity to activity, but probably would be better to explore other options like storing it in the Application class or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

**way 1 :**

make a `Constance class` and change value on that class and in another activity check that for new value

**way 2 :**

use `Intent` and put data and value in `extras` then call `activity`

**way 3 :**

create and use `interface` listeners

**way 4:(seem good way)**

use `EventBus` library : https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

any time you need sen notify to another activity via :

```
    EventBus.getDefault().post("notify param");
```

then handle notify in another activity :

```
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
    public void onMessageEvent("notify param") {/* Do something */};
```

(for more details to using `EventBus` look [library documents on github](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus#eventbus-in-3-steps))

Comment: can you explain the handling notify section... It show error..?

Comment: where have problem? - for `EventBus ` just read library completely & careful - that explain clearly

Comment: you add library in gradle(compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0')? - and register it in `onResum` and unregister in `onStop`?

Answer (score 0):

By using listeners. Follow this guide. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners

Answer (score 0):

You can set your return variable as **"Public static"** , from the current Activity Class you can call the public static variable and display its value from previous class.

Note: The value would diminish if the previous activity class is refreshed or destroyed making its value to null , from it you would probably get NullPointerException

Comment: can you explain.?

Comment: @Tom for example your asynctask method is on Activity A declare your variable as public static here and initialize its value and when you go to Activity B you can simply call it within Activity B.                                          `ActivityA mActivityA = new ActivityA    String getValue = mActivityA.<your variable>`